# Remove an XML Node if an attribute has a specific value

Tags: java, xml, dom, xpath

I have the need to search into an XML for some attributes and delete its Node if the attribute is found. For example, I want to remove the book nodes which have attributes beginning with "#false"

```
<catalog>
   <book id="bk101" available="#false">
      <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
      <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
      <genre>Computer</genre>
      <price>44.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
      <description>An in-depth look at creating applications 
      with XML.</description>
   </book>
</catalog>
```

So far, I have been able to capture all "#false" Elements using an XPath expression:

```
String search = "//@*[starts-with(.,'#false')]";
NodeList nodeList = (NodeList) xPath.
              compile(search).evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);

((Node)nodeList.item(0)).getParent(); // NULL!!
```

However the problem is that the Parent Node of "available" Elements is null so I cannot find a way to remove the whole "book" Node. Any help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For attributes, use `Attr#getOwnerElement()` to retrieve the element containing the attribute:

```
NodeList nodeList = (NodeList) xPath.
             compile(search).evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);

Node attrNode = nodeList.item(0);
if(attrNode.getNodeType() == Node.ATTRIBUTE_NODE) {
    Attr attr = (Attr) attrNode;

    Element bookElement = attr.getOwnerElement();
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use this xpath .. which will match with the book element itself

```
//*[@*[starts-with(.,'#false')]]
```

I hope this could help!